# How can I track the cause of random reboots?

Tags: reboot, log

A Thinkpad X220 (Core-i5, SandyBridge, Intel GMA) running Precise 64-bit has rebooted hard twice in the last four days. I was doing nothing more than writing an email. No warning. It just went black, and the next thing I saw was the Lenovo boot screen.

Where should I look to find the cause? I fear that this immediate reboot does not leave time for logs to be written...

Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

Check `/proc/sys/kernel/panic`; if its value is 1 then the server will immediately reboot on panic. Buggy drivers can cause a kernel panic.

If it's not a panic check last issue of reboot, maybe overheating is the issue.

```
last reboot
```

Comment: This command shows that my system came up with a new kernel.  Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit. 3.2.0-63 after reboot, 3.2.0-61 before

Comment: This led me to checking `etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`  I had set  `Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "true";`  I changed it back to the default setting of false.

Comment: @Antonios does this auto reboot is without warning?

Comment: @insider I got a strange log as the previous session is linked to the current one? `18:30 - 18:38  (00:07)` and before the sudden reboot `13:27 - 18:38  (05:11)`

Comment: `last |head -n 50` wow, I just found this: `13:55 - crash  (04:35)` what gonna track how that happened, thx!

Comment: @AquariusPower Yes, it was.  my issue went away after changing the unattended-upgrades setting.

Comment: I too am having the same issue. `last | head -n 50` showed `pts/14       :0               Thu Jul 14 08:28 - crash  (00:00)` and `:0           :0               Thu Jul 14 08:27 - crash  (00:01)`

Answer (score 18):

#### Commands

1. `dmesg` - May not show items from before last boot, but very useful if the system is still up

#### Files

1. `/var/log/syslog` - System wide logger, use `tail /var/log/syslog` or `less /var/log/syslog`
2. `/var/log/kern.log` - Kernel log, same as above
3. `/var/log/*`

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. The problem is - as stated in my question - that the system is not up anymore. I believe that I had some kind of hardware issue.

Comment: I went on a quick google hunt to check if the above files persist across reboots (since I'm not infront of a linux computer atm) and I found this site, which I found extremely informative: http://www.softpanorama.info/Commercial_linuxes/troubleshooting.shtml

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the output of `dmesg` is supposed to help? My machine has just randomly rebooted, and if I understand your suggestion right, then `dmesg` cannot help here, right?

Comment: I would like to add this `grep "Jan 11 01" /var/log/* -rah 2>/dev/null |sort` so you can target the day and the hour (ubuntu 16.04 but some info are version independent)

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR:** @insider's answer, along with the comments by @Antonios Hadjigeorgalis led me to find that I had

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "true"
```

in

```
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99custom-unattended-upgrades
```

---

I was experiencing sudden reboots, mostly soon after turning my laptop on in the morning. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04. Running `last reboot` showed that the kernel version was usually newer after the sudden reboots:

```bsh
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-112-gener Wed Jul 22 10:07   still running
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-111-gener Wed Jul 22 10:01 - 10:06  (00:04)
...
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-111-gener Wed Jul 15 09:49 - 23:43  (13:53)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-109-gener Wed Jul 15 09:45 - 09:48  (00:03)
...
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-109-gener Fri Jul  3 09:14 - 17:37  (08:23)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-108-gener Fri Jul  3 09:08 - 09:13  (00:05)
```

Looking into `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`, I saw that `"Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot"` was commented out, and its default is supposedly false. I then ran the following:

```bsh
grep Reboot /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/*
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades:Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "false";
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades://Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time "02:00";
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99custom-unattended-upgrades:// Reboot automatically if necessary (e.g. on kernel upgrade), should be
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99custom-unattended-upgrades:Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "true";
```

And there was my problem - `Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "true";` in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99custom-unattended-upgrades`.

Answer (score 3):

Application crashes have crash files in `/var/crash/`; I'd also explore normal system logs which are your best bet. If the hardware shutdown you won't see anything in the systemd & message logs (*a HUGE clue!!*).  If Ubuntu was aware of shutdown you'll see that too as you'll see reasons for shutdown. (*If no details are found you'll need to check machine logs; ie. HOST OS if VM or hardware logs if on metal*)

To look at app crashes on this box

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:/de2900/ubuntu_64$   ls -la /var/crash
total 113484
drwxrwsrwt  2 root    whoopsie      4096 Feb 27 12:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 16 root    root          4096 Nov 29  2018 ..
-rw-------  1 root    whoopsie   1214905 Feb 26 08:28 irssi-scripts.0.crash
-rw-------  1 root    whoopsie   1193193 Feb 25 15:04 lvm2.0.crash
-rw-r-----  1 guiverc whoopsie 101162337 Feb 19 13:00 _usr_bin_clementine.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 guiverc whoopsie   5962296 Feb 26 23:31 _usr_bin_gnome-control-center.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 guiverc whoopsie   1519149 Feb 20 08:28 _usr_bin_light-locker.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 guiverc whoopsie   1327084 Feb 27 12:00 _usr_bin_totem-video-thumbnailer.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 guiverc whoopsie     96196 Feb 22 13:55 _usr_games_sgt-launcher.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 guiverc whoopsie   3685288 Feb 22 00:34 _usr_lib_ibus_ibus-ui-gtk3.1000.crash
```

Starting with application crashes is easy, so I'd look there first, however I can't really think of why a application crash could cause a reboot or shutdown; so I'd not expect to see anything meaningful there (if it's useful; it'll be after system logs).

To view system messages (for current session) you can use `dmesg`.  Because it'll show the current session only, you won't see a reason for the last shutdown (that was last session), but after an unclean shutdown I'd expect to see results of a `fsck` (because of unplanned shutdown).

The best clues however are in systemd journals, or `journalctl`. This is where I'd really look for clues on last shutdown, ie. it's here where I'd expect to see the lack of normal shutdown messages which means it's a clue of hardware shutdown (eg. cpu shutoff because of extreme heat threshold; a pin gets grounded with OS having no clue so messages just stop! and next message is normal booting of next session; such messages will be found in hardware logs assuming an enterprise server; consumer grade usually don't keep hardware logs).

Sometimes you can see clues of overheating in logs anyway; bad if the PSU has issues (PWR_GOOD drops) nothing will be found as CPU wasn't even aware of shutdown; I suspect hardware logs may miss this type of shutdown too (but lack of entries is still a clue!)

To further narrow down where to look though, will depend on what type of server, what is running on it, and details that haven't been provided.