# Understanding the output of last reboot

Tags: boot, kernel, reboot

I am trying to diagnose the reasons for random reboots on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine. I am strongly inclined to believe that this is a hardware problem given [my previous experience with the Gigabyte GA 970 G1 Gaming motherboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/788855/qualcomm-atheros-ar93xx-wireless-network-adapter-ubuntu-16-04-woes) around which this system is built.

Nevertheless, I am starting off by looking at the output of `last reboot` as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/386526/165546), and this is what I get:

```
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-34-generic Sat Aug 27 10:54   still running
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-34-generic Sat Aug 27 03:03   still running
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-34-generic Tue Aug 23 20:27   still running
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-34-generic Sat Aug 20 19:43   still running
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-34-generic Wed Aug 17 22:06   still running
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-34-generic Wed Aug 17 22:02 - 22:06  (00:03)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-34-generic Mon Aug 15 14:37 - 22:06 (2+07:28)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-34-generic Wed Aug 10 11:03 - 22:06 (7+11:02)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-31-generic Sun Aug  7 15:54 - 22:06 (10+06:11)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-31-generic Sun Aug  7 13:43 - 15:54  (02:10)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-31-generic Sat Aug  6 18:27 - 15:54  (21:26)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-31-generic Sat Aug  6 17:55 - 18:25  (00:30)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-31-generic Mon Aug  1 15:08 - 18:25 (5+03:17)

wtmp begins Mon Aug  1 15:08:37 2016
```

It is not clear to me how several reboots could be "still running" at the same time. At first, I thought that this was a kernel thing -- all reboots from the same (latest) kernel are all marked as "still running", but that is clearly not the case.

Can someone please point to a source that explains how to systematically read this output?

---

If I were to guess, I would say that those are all the reboots that were not user initiated/sessions that were not correctly terminated. Is there any way to corroborate this?

Comment: And, shamelessly adding to your questions, does `2+` mean it has been running for *2 days*?

Comment: @grooveplex could you explain how adding to a question causes "shame"? I thought clarification with more details was a good thing? And what do you mean by "2+"? Apologies in advance for my ignorance but I don't want to lose face in the future.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1199551/interpreting-last-reboot-output Adding related link. Hope you find it useful